# Multiple connections to a TCP server

Tags: go, tcp, chat

I've developed a small Go TCP server to make a chat application. But when I try to connect clients to it, the server works fine with two clients, but whenever I tried to connect the third client it is not connected to the server. I am running on Windows. What could be the issue?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

var allClients map[*Client]int

type Client struct {
    // incoming chan string
    outgoing   chan string
    reader     *bufio.Reader
    writer     *bufio.Writer
    conn       net.Conn
    connection *Client
}

func (client *Client) Read() {
    for {
        line, err := client.reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err == nil {
            if client.connection != nil {
                client.connection.outgoing <- line
            }
            fmt.Println(line)
        } else {
            break
        }

    }

    client.conn.Close()
    delete(allClients, client)
    if client.connection != nil {
        client.connection.connection = nil
    }
    client = nil
}

func (client *Client) Write() {
    for data := range client.outgoing {
        client.writer.WriteString(data)
        client.writer.Flush()
    }
}

func (client *Client) Listen() {
    go client.Read()
    go client.Write()
}

func NewClient(connection net.Conn) *Client {
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(connection)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(connection)

    client := &Client{
        // incoming: make(chan string),
        outgoing: make(chan string),
        conn:     connection,
        reader:   reader,
        writer:   writer,
    }
    client.Listen()

    return client
}

func main() {
    allClients = make(map[*Client]int)
    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        client := NewClient(conn)
        for clientList, _ := range allClients {
            if clientList.connection == nil {
                client.connection = clientList
                clientList.connection = client
                fmt.Println("Connected")
            }
        }
        allClients[client] = 1
        fmt.Println(len(allClients))
    }
}
```

Comment: You get an error when connecting the third client? What is that error?

Comment: You can't use a map concurrently. Check your code with the race detector.

Comment: @AJPennster I am getting 
GetFileAttributesEx client.go: The system cannot find the file specified. Error on the client side on the server side I am not seeing anything. I am running on windows.

Comment: You should add the full error to your question, along with the code for the client.  If it panics, add the traceback as well.

Comment: @shubham003 What is the max no of TCP client you are able to get?

Comment: Your problem is in the client but you've only posted server code? Your problem is with a file but you are blaming TCP connections?

Comment: can this post be salvaged ? 5yo. OP will never follow up to figure out what he misunderstand at that time. And the big thing is, what does this do ? Does it broadcast to all others (should be), or just maintain some conns up, and echo them ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I compiled in on Linux, tried with 4 connections. Everything worked as expected.

Comment: So can it be OS specific issue. I'll try on Linux. Thanks